# Does android auto restore function when I install my app over the usb port in development mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, stock-android, usb-debugging, restore

Does android auto restore  when I  install my app over the usb port in development mode?

Comment: Do you mean installation via android debug bridge (adb)?  you can switches while installing apks to effect different results use

Comment: When  I "Run" or "Debug" from my SDK  with  my phone connected by USB,  my application is installed on my phone. I'm trying to get my application data transferred from my old phone to my new phone. I can  see from my google account that I have a backup in the cloud, but I can't get it to restore. When I  use adb shell bmgr com.example.mynewmap example I get  a generic message  "unable to restore data. I'm trying to restore a preferences file and a database file that were backed yup with basckupManaggerHelper.

Comment: I meant to type  "adb shell bmgr restore  com.example.mynewmapexample " which is my PACKAGE name.

Comment: I have no idea where I will find a token value for my previously stored backup file. I  didn't think it was required when using backupManagerHelper

Comment: Didn't find my PACKAGE in token list. Since my backup  is a key/value backup I don't think there is a token value for it.

Comment: Ok lets try this `bmgr list sets` ( the 64-bit hex number on the left is the token we want)

Comment: Any luckwith the last option?

Comment: No luck. The list command  gave me a backup set for both of the phones but restore would not restore across phones but only to the phone it originated from.